# User uploads image as "Featured Image" but WordPress resizes it?

Tags: images, uploads, media

I have a user with permissions of `Author` uploading an 800x238 image to WordPress as a Featured Image.

When it's uploading, I can see that it uploads correctly:

```
https://ygoprodeck.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Swordsoul-Grandmaster-Chixiao-Banner-1-1.png
```

However, something seems to happen between there and attaching it to a post, Wordpress appends `800x330` to the URL:

```
https://ygoprodeck.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Swordsoul-Grandmaster-Chixiao-Banner-1-1-800x330.png
```

This does not happen when I (`Admin`) do it.

I've checked `Settings -> Media` but I'm still not sure where the `800x330` is coming from.

Is it possible to disable this functionality for this particular user? There must be some sort of permission involved considering I can upload and attach without this occurring.

Comment: Are you certain the author is uploading the same image as you? They appear to be uploading a larger image. The 800x330 is because your theme has defined a custom image size for featured images. Your version of the image would not be getting resized because it is smaller than the defined size.

Comment: Oh my goodness you are completely correct. We both use a system I designed to generate the image for the user but my other user seems to be getting it in a slightly different size for some reason. Not sure how I managed to miss that. Thank you! Now, all that confusion makes perfect sense.